# Update duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id    name
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     b
5     b
6     c
```

I am looking for an update statement that will update `name` column to:

```
id    name
1     a
2     a-2
3     a-3
4     b
5     b-2
6     c
```

In `SQL Server` I would use:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by id) rn from table)
update cte set name = name + '-' + cast(rn as varchar(10))
where rn <> 1
```

I am not strong in `MySQL` nonstandard queries. 
Can I do something like this in `MySQL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE YourTable p
       JOIN(SELECT t.id,t.name,count(*) as rnk
            FROM YourTable t
            INNER JOIN YourTable s on(t.name = s.name and t.id <= s.id)
            GROUP BY t.id,t.name) f
       ON(p.id = f.id)
SET p.name = concat(p.name,'-',f.rnk)
WHERE rnk > 1
```

This will basically use join and count to get the same as ROW_NUMBER() , and update only those who have more then 1 result(meaning the second,third ETC excluding the first)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Let me try this.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri No problem, let me know if you have any errors

Comment: Nope, it updated only 1 row and set count to something close to number of rows 7438 while number of rows is 7412.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Oh , sorry forgot to add the group by clause.. will work now

Comment: No problem:) @GiorgiNakeuri

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL you can use variables in order to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(name, IF(rn = 1, '', CONCAT('-', rn))) AS name
FROM (
SELECT id, name,
       @rn := IF(name = @n, @rn + 1,
                 IF(@n := name, 1, 1)) AS rn
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @n := '') AS vars
ORDER BY name, id) AS t
```

To `UPDATE` you can use:

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
SET name = (
   SELECT CONCAT(name, IF(rn = 1, '', CONCAT('-', rn))) AS name
   FROM (
      SELECT id, name,
             @rn := IF(name = @n, @rn + 1,
                       IF(@n := name, 1, 1)) AS rn
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @n := '') AS vars
   ORDER BY name, id) AS t2
   WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0e2d/1)

You can also use `UPDATE` with `JOIN` syntax:

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT id, rn, CONCAT(name, IF(rn = 1, '', CONCAT('-', rn))) AS name
   FROM (
      SELECT id, name,
             @rn := IF(name = @n, @rn + 1,
                       IF(@n := name, 1, 1)) AS rn
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @n := '') AS vars
      ORDER BY name, id) AS x
) AS t2 ON t2.rn <> 1 AND t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.name = t2.name;
```

The latter is probably faster than the former because it performs less `UPDATE` operations.

Comment: I have tried the last statement and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Glad I was able to help you. Cheers Giorgi!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! You were first but I should accept @sagi's answer, because it is more readable and standard for me.

Answer (score 2):

The next query will do it with less effort for the database:

```
UPDATE
    tab AS tu
INNER JOIN
    --  result set containing only duplicate rows that must to be updated
    (
        SELECT
            t.id,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM
            tab AS t
        --  join the same table by smaller id and equal value. That way you will exclude rows that are not duplicated
        INNER JOIN
            tab AS tp
        ON
            tp.name = t.name
        AND
            tp.id < t.id
        GROUP BY
            t.id
    ) AS tc
ON
    tu.id = tc.id
SET
    tu.name = CONCAT(tu.name, '-', tc.cnt + 1)
```